# How to embedd external plugin like "BWP Gazetteer" with GATE

Tags: nlp, gate

I would like to use `BWP Gazetteer` instead of Default Gazetteer of GATE. For this, i added it as a resource in `creole.xml` and included its JAR as well in the workspace.

Creole.xml

```
  <RESOURCE>
<NAME>BWPGazetteer</NAME>
<JAR>BWPGazetteer.jar</JAR>
<CLASS>bwp.gate.gazetteer.BWPGazetteer</CLASS>
<COMMENT>A BWPGazetteer.</COMMENT>
  <PARAMETER NAME="document" RUNTIME="true"
    COMMENT="The document to be processed"> gate.Document</PARAMETER>
  <PARAMETER NAME="annotationSetName" RUNTIME="true"
    COMMENT="The annotation set to be used for the generated annotations"
    OPTIONAL="true">java.lang.String</PARAMETER>
  <PARAMETER NAME="listsURL"
    DEFAULT="resources/gazetteer/lists.def"
    COMMENT="The URL to the file with list of lists" SUFFIXES="def">
    java.net.URL</PARAMETER>
  <PARAMETER DEFAULT="UTF-8"
    COMMENT="The encoding used for reading the definitions" NAME="encoding">
    java.lang.String</PARAMETER>
  <PARAMETER DEFAULT="true"
    COMMENT="Should this gazetteer diferentiate on case"
    NAME="caseSensitive">java.lang.Boolean</PARAMETER>
  <PARAMETER DEFAULT="true"
    COMMENT="Should this gazetteer only match whole words"
    NAME="wholeWordsOnly">java.lang.Boolean</PARAMETER>
    <PARAMETER NAME="normalizedDistanceThreshold"
            COMMENT="Maximum normalized distance(0.0-1.0) for a match"
            DEFAULT="0.1">
            java.lang.Double
        </PARAMETER>
<PARAMETER DEFAULT="true"
    COMMENT="Should this gazetter avoid overlapping annotations"
    NAME= "avoidOverlapingAnnotations">
    java.lang.Boolean
</PARAMETER>
```

Can anyone tell me what further changes are required in my JAVA code or config files to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to modify any creole.xml files, you just download and unpack the BWPGazetteer distribution, load the `BWPGazetteer` directory as a CREOLE plugin, create an instance of the gazetteer and slot it into your pipeline in the appropriate place.  By far the easiest approach to this is to use GATE Developer to build your pipeline (including the relevant gazetteer instance(s) in the right place(s)), then right click and "Export for GATECloud.net".  This will produce a zip file containing a saved application state (application.xgapp) and all the plugins and resource files the application uses.

Unpack this zip file somewhere in your project and then you can simply use `PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile` (or `loadObjectFromUrl`) to load the saved application along with all the plugins it requires.

Comment: Sorry but am a newbie and didn't clearly understood the approach. By `load the BWPGazetteer directory as a CREOLE plugin`, did u mean copying it (just the BWPGazetter.JAR) into plugins folder? In my Java project, the hieararchy is like : GATE->Plugins->ANNIE (ANNIE->resources,build.xml,creole.xml)!

Comment: @DivyaMotiwala Download the plugin zip file, unzip it, then in GATE Developer open the plugin manager, click the `+` button at the top left, click the folder button, and select the `BWPGazetteer` directory you just unpacked.  This will add the plugin to the list below, and you can then tick the relevant "load now" box to load the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for all the help :) It worked. Can you tell me the performance implication of BWP Gazetteer as i could notice drastic performance issue after using it. It takes a lot of time for processing. Any insight on this is appreciated :)

Comment: @DivyaMotiwala I'm afraid I know nothing about the BWP gazetteer plugin specifically, beyond what's on its own website.  My answer to this question is simply the generic way to load any third-party plugin into GATE.

Comment: @DivyaMotiwala `BWPGazetteer` is slow by its nature. It does proximate string matching using the `Levenshtein's Distance` which takes much more time than ordinary gazetteer matching. Try to minimize the `normalizedDistanceTreshold` to speed it up a little, but I'm afraid it will not help. I think `BWPGazetteer` is usable for small gazetteer lists only.